Tax is not reflecting with SI Create request API in Sage Intacct Sales Invoice
I am using sage intacct's web services API for creating AR sales invoice. In the XML request there is specific property for sending tax detail, but when I am sending it the invoice is getting created with the line details but the tax is not reflecting anywhere.
Here is the XML request which I am posting
Documentation followed: https://developer.intacct.com/api/accounts-receivable/invoices/#create-invoice-legacy
Endpoint URL: https://api.intacct.com/ia/xml/xmlgw.phtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <control>
    <senderid>{{sender_id}}</senderid>
    <password>{{sender_password}}</password>
    <controlid>{{$timestamp}}</controlid>
    <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>
    <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
    <includewhitespace>false</includewhitespace>
  </control>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <sessionid>{{session_id}}</sessionid>
    </authentication>
    <content>
        <function controlid="123456">
        <create_invoice>
          <customerid>DWL-CUS00020</customerid>
          <datecreated>
            <year>2018</year>
            <month>03</month>
            <day>31</day>
          </datecreated>
          <dateposted>
            <year>2018</year>
            <month>05</month>
            <day>31</day>
          </dateposted>
          <datedue>
            <year>2018</year>
            <month>04</month>
            <day>30</day>
          </datedue>
          <termname></termname>
          <batchkey></batchkey>
          <action>Submit</action>
          <invoiceno>TEST-21</invoiceno>
          <ponumber>OBTEST-21</ponumber>
          <description>Opening Balance</description>
          <externalid></externalid>
          <billto>
            <contactname></contactname>
          </billto>
          <shipto>
            <contactname></contactname>
          </shipto>
          <basecurr>GBP</basecurr>
          <currency>GBP</currency>
          <exchratedate>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>04</month>
            <day>1</day>
          </exchratedate>
          <exchratetype>Goodwill and Investment by BLS Inter.</exchratetype>
          <nogl>false</nogl>
          <supdocid></supdocid>
          <customfields>
            <customfield>
              <customfieldname></customfieldname>
              <customfieldvalue></customfieldvalue>
            </customfield>
          </customfields>
          <taxsolutionid></taxsolutionid>
          <invoiceitems>
            <lineitem>
              <glaccountno>16110</glaccountno>
              <offsetglaccountno></offsetglaccountno>
              <amount>10.00</amount>
              <memo></memo>
              <locationid>Entity Name</locationid>
              <departmentid></departmentid>
              <key></key>
              <totalpaid>10.00</totalpaid>
              <totaldue>0</totaldue>
              <customfields>
                <customfield>
                  <customfieldname></customfieldname>
                  <customfieldvalue></customfieldvalue>
                </customfield>
              </customfields>
              <revrectemplate></revrectemplate>
              <defrevaccount></defrevaccount>
              <revrecstartdate>
                <year></year>
                <month></month>
                <day></day>
              </revrecstartdate>
              <revrecenddate>
                <year></year>
                <month></month>
                <day></day>
              </revrecenddate>
              <projectid></projectid>
              <customerid>DWL-CUS00020</customerid>
              <vendorid></vendorid>
              <employeeid></employeeid>
              <itemid></itemid>
              <classid></classid>
              <warehouseid></warehouseid>
              <taxentries>
                <taxentry>
                    <detailid>VAT</detailid>
                    <trx_tax>2.00</trx_tax>
                </taxentry>
              </taxentries>
            </lineitem>
          </invoiceitems>
        </create_invoice>
      </function>
    </content>
  </operation>
</request>

And this is the screen shot of the invoice

screen shot of Tax Authority

screen shot of Tax Details

screen shot of Tax schedule maps

screen shot of Tax schedule

I will be happy to share any other info if required.

I am looking for answers to a similar question. Did you ever figure it out?

No @the_brianb with the API i was not able to find any solution, later we did it by importing excel sheets with entire invoice data.
